# prevent modal close on submit (Laravel/Bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I don't see an easy solution to this so will be chuffed if proved wrong.
In short, modal dialog pops up, user enters a non-unique value, submit causes field validation to fail but modal still closes:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="newtargetModal"
       tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
       aria-labelledby="newtargetModalLabel">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">Target (e.g. hostname)
                <button type="button" class="close"
                   data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              @include('applications.add')
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

the include (applications.add):

```
{!! Form::open( ['method'=> 'POST', 'action'=> 'supportedAppsController@store', 'class'=>'form-horizontal'] ) !!}
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('app_name') ? ' has-error' : 'unique:supported_apps:app_name' }}">
<label for="app_name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="app_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="app_name" style="margin-bottom: 10px"
           value="{{ old('app_name') }}" required autofocus>
    @if ($errors->has('app_name'))
        <span class="help-block">
           <strong>{{ $errors->first('app_name') }}</strong>
           </span>
    @endif
</div>
</div> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" class=" btn-primary" value="Add">
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

In the case validation finds the app_name not to be unique when the Add button is pressed, the modal closes. When reopened it can be seen the $error handling has flagged up with "The app name has already been taken".
The include is used in another piece of code (not in a modal). I wondered if there is a way to prevent the Add button closing the modal in the case $error is set.
Thanks in advance for any advice on this one.
Kevin

Edit:

I did try the following:

```
 $(document).ready()
            {
                @if(count($errors)>0)
                  $('#newtargetModal').modal('show');
                @endif
             }
```

But I don't want to answer my own question yet.. It seems a cheeky solution but I've not tested it enough. Initial test suggests it gets round the problem of popping the dialog back up....

Comment: Yes you need to make the form submit via ajax... and then if there were errors the page will not submit and it will stay put, and it should show the errors

Comment: Thanks, I got that impression from another similar question but was hoping mine was sufficiently different such that it could be achieved without Ajax. Pity to have to do the extra work!

Comment: yeah Unfortunately if you try to submit with just HTML it will jump to that function immediately. I will make my comment as answer OK. I will make an example...just a moment please

Answer (score 0):

In order to submit the form and prevent the page reload or redirect on error you need to submit it via ajax. That way you can see the errors.

```
$(document).on('mousedown touch', ':submit', function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    var form = $("form");

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'your route',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{csrf_token()}}" },
        data: form.serializeArray(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log('validated!');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            var errorsArr = [];

            for (error in errors) {
                errorsArr.push(errors[error][0]);
            }

            swal({text: "<strong class='text-danger'>" + errorsArr.join("<br>") + "</strong>"});
            console.log("validation failed");
        }

    });
});
```

I am using sweetalert 2 plugin for this so you will have to adjust that part to your needs, but this is it.